# Condition for nontrivial homomorphism to exist between two groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

What might be the condition for nontrivial homomorphism to exist between two groups?

Is it true that for $\psi: K \to H$, there is nontrivial homomorphic $\psi$ exists if they contain a common prime divisor $p$? Are there any established results on this? For example, I know $\psi: Z_3 \to S_3$ can be nontrivial by mapping the entire $Z_3$ to order 3 subgroup of $S_3$. But what about the general case.

Comment: I'm assuming $K, H$ are finite groups? I'm not sure there is an easy condition. Your condition is not sufficient. For example, there is no non-trivial homomorphism from $A_5\to C_2$, since $A_5$ is simple.

Comment: How does $A_5$ being simple prevent it from having a non-trivial homomorphism?

Comment: The kernel of such a map would have to be non-trivial

Comment: More generally, if $G$ is a simple group and $K$ is another group such that $G$ does not embed in $K$, there is no nontrivial morphism $G\to K$. Indeed, $\mathrm{Ker}f$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ so it's $G$ or $1$: if it's $1$, $f$ is injective and is thus an embedding; if it's $G$, $f$ is trivial